# How insert value from Ruby in CSS file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am seeking for method to insert some ruby code in css (sass).

For example i wanna replace setting of background color in my admin area and wrote it in model `Setting.find_by_name('ui_background_color').value`

How in css (sass) i can replace this value ?

Comment: Append `.erb` to the file and then use `<%= ruby code %>` to insert ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails asset pipeline automatically evaluates `ERB`, if you have the `.erb` extension. Please see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb.

You can then inject Ruby by using `ERB` syntax:

```
<%= ruby code %> # Evaluate and display result
<% ruby code %> # Silently evaluate
```